# USB tethering - how to access files using ip of my pc from other machines?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, usb, apache-http-server, android

I have apache server running in my machine. I have connected my pc to internet using an android phone's USB tethering feature. Now, I would like to access the files (that are hosted in my pc using apache server) via my phone.

Ex: 
now I am accessing the files using this URL in from my pc

http://localhost/project-API/

I would like to access the same URL from some other devices also using the ip address.

like this: http://my_Machine_Ip/project-API

After some exploration I found that we have to set static ip to the pc which hosts the files. If I set static ip to my pc it wont connect to the internet and the netwrok center shows no internet connection(Ofcourse USB tethering is switched on and internet is also working in phone). Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a static IP, you just need to know its current address (and have the web server bound to it, of course).

Comment: I tried accessing the current ip (assigned by DHCP) from my phone. But it is not working. " have the web server bound to it " I don't understand what you're saying. can you explain a bit? I am using XAMP server in  my pc..

Comment: Regardless of the type of connection you're using, as long as it isn't from inside the server's network, you need port forwarding rules in the router at the very least.

Comment: @MichaelBay To connect with internet in PC, I am using USB tethering feature from my phone. So, I assume that my phone acts as a router to my PC. If my assumption is correct I need to set some port forwarding rules in my phone?